# Bldc motor braking

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, braking

Which type of braking is most suitable for bldc motor?
Plugging or dynamic or degenerative braking.
For motion control application.

Comment: It depends on the application.

Comment: @briabn Drummond ..it is used in motion control

Comment: it depends on the system: can you regen on the powersupply, how much energy needs to be dissipated.  There are a number of mechanisms to brake and this is because there isn't a univeraal solution

Comment: "Motion control" says precisely nothing about the application.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging is almost always a bad choice. It can not be controlled very well and it can be stressful for the motor.

Dynamic braking dissipates energy in braking in resistors and in the inherent losses in the motor and control system. It is a good alternative if there is not a lot of energy involved. To evaluate that, you need to examine the inertia, energy use and losses in the driven mechanical load. The control requirements depend on the performance required, but it generally less complicated and costly than regenerative braking.

Regenerative (not degenerative) braking returns braking energy to the power supply. To do that you need to evaluate the capacity of the power supply to accept the returned energy. The power electronic circuits of the motor control unit needs to be designed to return braking energy.

The decision depends on cost, importance of conserving energy, evaluation of design complexity and personal preference.